# Error on playing music on QT

Tags: qt, multimedia

[image: I was trying to play a music on a push button. But it shows this error. Please help. Thanks]

I have included all the header and others to do this. But cannot overcome the error.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code; post the text of the code instead.

Comment: The error you are getting is "Out of memory allocating 1073745919 bytes."  That doesn't tell me much more than it does you; except that I know a simple program like this has no excuse for running the computer out of memory, either at compile or run time.  How big are all your files?

Comment: Sorry. my bad. I will keep in mind in future :)

Comment: around 3 mega byte

Comment: We're going to need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before we can help you at all.     Please read and follow the instructions on that page.

Comment: That error message is for allocation of 1,073,745,919 bytes, which is just slightly over 1 GB. Check that you aren't including something bad in the .qrc file.

Answer (score 1):

The Qt resource system will try to place the .mp3 files inside your binary.
Move the .mp3 files out of .qrc .
From the Qt documentation:

> will produce make rules to generate a file called qrc_application.cpp >that is linked into the application. This file contains all the data for the >images and other resources as static C++ arrays of compressed binary data.

Your mp3 files are too big to fit inside these static arrays.

Comment: If comment of OP is accurate, then 3 MB file should fit easily.

Comment: It's possible that the compiler in use takes quite a bit more than 3MB to process a 3MB static array, but blowing up by three orders of magnitude strikes me as implausibly bad.